# Marking items read in a For Each loop leaves some marked unread

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to mark messages, copied from within an Outlook subfolder to Inbox into a file system folder, as read.

```vb
Sub demo1()
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim path As String
    Dim i As Integer, iUnred As Integer
    Dim objUnreadItems As Object, m As Object, att As Object, Item As Object
    
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item("user@email.com") ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("SubFolder")
    
    Set objUnreadItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
    ' Debug.Print objUnreadItems.Count
    
    If objUnreadItems.Count = 0 Then
   '     MsgBox "NO objUnreadItems Email In Inbox" TODO: add to logfile
    Else
    
        For Each Item In objUnreadItems
            'Debug.Print objUnreadItems.Count
            path = "C:\temp\" & Item.Subject & ".msg"
            Item.SaveAs path, olMSG
            'Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic
            ' Item.unRead = False
        Next
        For Each Item In objFolder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
            Debug.Print objUnreadItems.Count & ": " & Item.ConversationTopic
            Item.unRead = False
        Next
   End If
End Sub
```

output looks like:

9: FA Report for RMA# 2832844
9: FA Report for RMA# 2828196
8: FA Report for RMA# 2827687
7: FA Report for RMA# 2827667
6: FA Report for RMA# 2832909

All messages show up in c:\temp but only five out of the nine messages are marked as read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying (by setting the `UnRead` property) the collection as you iterate over its elements. Replace `for each` with a down loop:

```
for i = objUnreadItems.Count to 1 step -1
      set item = objUnreadItems(i)
      path = "C:\temp\" & Item.Subject & ".msg"
      Item.SaveAs path, olMSG
      Item.UnRead = False
next
```

You might also want to cleanup the file name by removing invalid (for a file name) characters, such as `:`.

Comment: The item is not removed from the collection when a property is set. Why do we need to replace `foreach` with `for` in that case?

Comment: The collections are dynamic - they can get updated if the condition is no longer satisfied due to change in the UnRead property.

Comment: Interesting, I'll double check that.

Comment: it works but not perfectly.  sometimes the messages are getting left unread

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to which messages are left unread? Are all unread messages getting saved as MSG files?